# How can I get T-SQL to include correct data from last month

Tags: t-sql

In the below query I return data for past 5 months, unfortunately I can not get it to include correct count from current month (June 2021), it ruturns 0 where as it should have returned 2 since I have 2 entries with StartDate 14-06-2021 and 17-06-2021 which should have been in this count.. How can I fix this?.

**The output I get (missing 2 in month 6)**

```
year    month   EmployeeStartet
2021     2           8
2021     3           0
2021     4           0
2021     5           4
2021     6           0
```

**My Query**

```
declare @thismonth1 as Date = DateAdd(
  d, 
  1 - DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
declare @lastMonth1 as Date = DateAdd(
  d, 
  1 - DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
declare @firstMonth1 as Date = DateAdd(m, -4, @lastMonth1);
WITH months AS (
  SELECT 
    @firstMonth1 AS thisMonth 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    DateAdd(m, 1, thisMonth) AS thisMonth 
  FROM 
    months 
  WHERE 
    thisMonth < @lastMonth1
), 
data AS (
  SELECT 
    YEAR(StartDate) year, 
    MONTH(StartDate) month, 
    COUNT(StartDate) EmployeeStartet 
  FROM 
    EFP_EmploymentUser 
  WHERE 
    EmployType = 'fixed' 
    AND StartDate BETWEEN @firstmonth1 
    AND @thismonth1 
  GROUP BY 
    YEAR(StartDate), 
    MONTH(StartDate)
) 
SELECT 
  YEAR(m.thisMonth) AS year, 
  MONTH(m.thisMonth) AS month, 
  ISNULL(d.EmployeeStartet, 0) AS EmployeeStartet 
FROM 
  months m 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN data d ON d.year = YEAR(m.thisMonth) 
  AND d.month = MONTH(m.thisMonth) 
ORDER BY 
  m.thisMonth ASC;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Tip: Formattingwithappropriateuseofwhitespaceandindentationmakesitmucheasiertoreadcodesamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
declare @thismonth1 as Date = DateAdd(d, 1 - DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
declare @lastMonth1 as Date = DateAdd(d, 1 - DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
declare @firstMonth1 as Date = DateAdd(m, -4, @lastMonth1);

select @thismonth1, @lastMonth1, @firstMonth1;
```

This gives you

| @thismonth1 | @lastMonth1 | @firstMonth1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-02-01 |

Correct @lastMonth1 and your query will run just fine. You can use `EOMONTH` for this.

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner the EOMONTH in both thismonth1 and lastMonth1 fixed it, and I have now the correct data output :-)